# Update UI from another Class Method - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface

I would like to update the UI in my application from the AppDelegate, but whenever I call it as so:

```
Controller *object = [[Controller alloc] init];
[object methodHere];
```

It doesn't seem to update the UI. What am I doing wrong here? I have put in a NSLog to see if it was being called, and it is. [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?fvcqn4ye9ashaht) is a sample project that shows the error.

Edit: Can someone just show me what to change to the project I provided. I just don't know what to type into my project so that I can change the value of a simple NSTextField from another class.

Comment: Why did you start a bounty -- what is it about the answers below that is lacking for you? They both seem to me to answer your question.

Comment: The code at that link doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. I can't find anything that looks like the code you say is supposed to be in your AppDelegate; there isn't even a text field in the interface!

Comment: No, there is a textfield. The nstextfield is in the Controller class.

Comment: I've posted the answer, including explanation, for you. Just ask if you need clarification or expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really simple, and Chuck's comments basically explain what you need to do, but I will lay out the code explicitly for you. In `testAppDelegate.h`:

```
@interface testAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    // You can make an IBOutlet to any kind of object you
    // want; it's just a way for you to get a reference
    // in code to an object that has been alloc'd and
    // init'd already by the xib mechanism.
    IBOutlet Controller *controller;

}
```

Then go into your xib in InterfaceBuilder and hook up that outlet from your Test App Delegate object to your Controller object (these objects are already present in the xib).

In `testAppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // This is the key:
    // _Don't_ alloc/init a new controller object. The 
    // objects in your xib are allocated and initialized 
    // by virtue of being in that file. You just need to 
    // give your AppDelegate a pointer to it, as above.
    [controller setTextValue:@"hello"];
}
```

Comment: Man I feel so stupid. Seemed so blatant but I just couldn't grasp it with all this new programming vocabulary. Well. Thanks so much Josh and Chuck. Also thanks again for going through the trouble of download the project and looking at it. :) I really appreciate it

Comment: @Kevin: Sure thing! The Cocoa paradigm can definitely be overwhelming at first. Fortunately, it's pretty well-organized, so it gets easier the further you get into it. Good luck, and don't forget to award that bounty!

Comment: Guys @lab12  Can you please provide a bit information for the line "Then go into your xib in InterfaceBuilder and hook up that outlet from your Test App Delegate object to your Controller object (these objects are already present in the xib)."  I am not getting it, Please Provide some sample Project for this, its a bit urgent for me.

Answer (score 9):

When you write `[[Controller alloc] init]`, you are not accessing the Controller object that is in your nib. You are creating a **new Controller object** that is unconnected to anything else in your application.

Remember, every Controller object is not the same any more than every NSArray is the same. Just because you made one Controller in your nib that's connected to an NSTextField does not mean some random Controller that you just created shares that controller's connections.

What you need to do is give the delegate a reference to the Controller that's in the nib.

Comment: But if I ran a method like so [object myMethod] it is calling it from the AppDelegate not the NSObject class I made called Controller

Comment: @Kevin: Sorry, I misunderstood which object was the delegate. I updated my answer. It's basically the same — you're not accessing the object you meant to access, just another object that happens to have the same class.

Comment: Yea, I kinda need help with your edit. I can't seem to find anywhere on how to do that. I've been searching for quite a while, can you please provide some more information?

Comment: @Kevin: The same way you give an object a reference to another in any other situation. You've already given the delegate a reference to a window and the Controller a reference to a text field. How did you do that? You either give the delegate an outlet and create a connection in IB, or you ask some other object that knows about the Controller for a reference to it (in the same way that you ask NSApp for its delegate).

Comment: Sorry chuck if I'm not really on target here, but how should I go about asking another object for a reference to Controller? I'm kinda new to this situation, so an example might be best. Please take a look at the example project on my post, and may you tell me what I must change? I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Kevin: You create an outlet in myAppDelegate and drag a connection from that outlet to the Controller in your xib. Then you can use that outlet to talk to the Controller.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I mean what type of IBOutlet am I suppose to create? How would I use it to communicate with the Controller?

Answer (score 3):

It's being called all right, but it's not connected to the interface. There should be a view controller of some sort defined in your appDelegate.h file, call the method on that object instead.

Update for more detail:
One way you could pull this off would be to simply save the Controller when you originally create it (and not release it until later.)

Simply put your own controller object into your .h file

```
Controller* myController;
```

And when you create the new view controller you want to flip to, simply set myController to reference that object, and later when you want to update the UI, simply call

```
[myController methodHere];
```

A bit clumsy, but it works. Just don't forget to release myController when you're done with that view.

The other idea I'd suggest looking into would be to alter the method you're passing to your delegate. That is, instead of having the method as

```
-(returnType)callDelegateToDoSomething;
```

put it in as

```
-(returnType)callDelegateToDoSomething:(id) sender;
```

You call the new method the same way, but your controller should automatically pass itself as an argument. Then, inside the method, simply use

```
[sender methodHere];
```

and it should hopefully work. (You may need to play around with it a little. I'm not an expert on delegates or the sender argument, but it's worth a shot.)

Comment: What do you mean "Connected to the interface"? I do believe that the IBOutlet from the second class is connected to the object, which is a NSTextField. I haven't really worked with the view controller much, can you show me how the code would look like?

Comment: Did you create your application from the basic window prototype? I advise creating a new application, and picking the view-based application. That has an app delegate with a view controller already made, and the view controller has it's own interface builder file. That should hopefully give you an idea of how it all works.

Comment: Umm. I am working with the Mac API system, not the iPhone. I don't believe there is such thing for the Mac.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Anyway, I've edited in a couple of possible ways you might be able to call your method correctly. Hopefully one of those might help out.

Comment: Either of those methods don't seem to work. HOW would I set myController to reference an object (just to be clear, what code would I specifically type?)