# NSTextfield not getting updated when called from another class

Tags: cocoa, uilabel, nstextfield

I have a runthis.h file where I have a label:

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *updateStatus;
```

Now in my runthis.m file, in a class called startTest I update this using

```
-(IBAction) startTest:(id)sender {
        [updateStatus setStringValue:@"Testing"];
}
```

Now if I create an object for the runthis class in another file testing.m and then try this:

```
 runthis *testSomething = [[runthis alloc] init];
[testSomething performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startTest:) withObject:nil];
```

But I find the UI for the label *updateStatus will never get set to "Testing" when I call it from testing.m
If I call this directly from runthis.m, then the UI gets updated as expected. Any ideas why ? Thanks.

Comment: This answered my question for those interested:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082018/update-ui-from-another-class-method-cocoa

Answer (score 1):

Unless `runthis` is located in a separate nib, it's outlet won't be connected automatically, you'll have to pass it as a reference. In `testing` you'll have to wire up the text field, then pass it to `runthis` like:

```
[testSomething setStatusField:updateStatus];
```

Or you could create a reference to your `testing` object from your `runthis` object (call it a delegate) and have `testing` update the UI directly. That's the approach I would use.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your comment. How would I create a ref. to the testing object from runthis and update the UI directly ?

Comment: @ZionKing: Add a property to your `runthis` object that takes a `testing` object—or something that conforms to a protocol that `runthis` declares. Have `testing` conform to the protocol (if you go that way) and set itself as the `runthis`'s delegate. When `runthis` needs to get the field's value changed, have it send a message to its delegate, and have the `testing` object respond to that message by getting the `runthis` object's `statusField` and setting its value.

Comment: Not sure I get this yet. Are there any examples ? Thanks and appreciate all the help and patience :).